# How can I make a list into a matrix? Not experienced with R

Tags: r

I have a list that I want to convert it into a matrix: it has two vectors

What's the easiest way to convert a simple list into a matrix?

Comment: More details please. Maybe just `do.call(rbind, yourList)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
lst <- list(a = c(1:3), b = c(4:6))
do.call(rbind, lst)
#   [,1] [,2] [,3]
# a    1    2    3
# b    4    5    6
```